# Task per branch with perforce

Tags: repository, perforce, branch

i'm preparing a seminary about p4 and i'm trying to find the best way to use the "Task per branch" methodology, now i'm using the following steps: (all by CLI)

- Set my client to the root depot in order to create the new branches.
  View:
  //depot/... //myMachine/...
- p4 -c myClient integ -v //depot/MAIN/... //depot/myBranchX/...
- p4 -c myClient submit -d "Branching"
- Change again my client aiming to the new branch.
  View:
  //depot/myBranchX/... //myMachine/...
- p4 -c myClient sync

i'm wondering if there's a fastest/better way to do it. Specially working with huge repositories and branches.

Thanks!
M.

Comment: Are the clergy that set on doing the task per branch methodology?  So far as I know, eventually this will bog down your Perforce repository.

Comment: Well, im not to much religious, but, do you mean that p4 is not "task per branch" ready?

Comment: Surely your title should be 'Branch per task'?

Comment: Indeed, the title must be "branch per task"

Answer (score 3):

So... you want to create a branch for *each* task/bug and you want the newly created branch to mapped to client/workspace as *if* it was the trunk. And you want to be able to this via the command line or by running a scrip. Correct?

OK.

What is there a reason you want to adopt this workflow? Are you working on critical software, i.e., life/death scenario where every task is isolated and **needs** to be thoroughly vetted before integrating into the main line.

Unless you have a situation like above I would recommend against this workflow. Creating a branch for every task, especially in a large repository will eventually bring your Perforce server to a crawl. An similar situation was posted recently on the Perforce Blog as an Anti-Pattern (what not to do). [Perforce Anti-Patterns Part 2: Overuse of branching.](http://www.perforce.com/blog/090512/perforce-anti-patterns-part-2-overuse-branching)

Think about it.

If you still want to proceed, then you can achieve what you want by writing a shell script (DOS, Bash, Python**) that groups the above commands together taking a few arguments for the task/branch name etc. Comment if you need further help in doing this.

** preferred, then compile the script using py2exe as an executable for distribution.